# Visual Studio installer does not launch

Tags: visual-studio

I've downloaded Visual Studio Community 2017 so I can program in Unity 5 and I tried to install it. When I launch it something loads and then nothing happens after that. I've looked at the task manager but the installer was not launched.

I've formatted my PC 3 days ago, I was using the same thins as now. Windows 10 on the same PC. The only change is that I only have 1 Partition now on the Disk.
I was already using Visuals Studio with Unity 5 and it worked perfectly.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks.
I'm sorry if I speak bad English, I'm from Germany.

Comment: is the installer not launching or visual studio not launching after install?

Comment: The Installer is not launching.

Comment: Did you download the installer or are you running it from the website?

Comment: I downloaded it. How do I run it from the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to format my Computer again for the Installer to work. I did not find any other way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if you have enough space.
Check if you have the required to run it.
And then launch as an administrator.

Comment: I have 750 GB of free space. I have the requirements to run it and I'm launching it as administrator.